# OpenCv imdecode returns none for HEIC file

Tags: python, opencv, heic

I am working on application to resize the images. It is working fine with image format of jpg, png, jpeg, but its not working as expected to heic files.

Error:
 `OpenCV(4.4.0) /tmp/pip-req-build-vu_aq9yd/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor'`

Code snipplet

```
        npimg = np.frombuffer(stream.read(), np.uint8)
        img = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imdecode(npimg, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        h, w = cls.get_dims(img, dpi)
        img = cv2.resize(img, (w, h), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
        return Image.fromarray(img).convert("RGB")
```

What I found is:

`cv2.imdecode(npimg, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)` returns  **none**.

I am not able to  figure out why its not working with heic file.
What can be the solution for this issue?

**Note**:

I had looked through the previous similar issue, but none of them worked for me.

Comment: You can read a HEIC file in Python with `wand` which is based on **ImageMagick**. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/54558699/2836621

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenCV do not support heic files. From OpenCV documentation:

```
Currently, the following file formats are supported:

    Windows bitmaps - *.bmp, *.dib (always supported)
    JPEG files - *.jpeg, *.jpg, *.jpe (see the Note section)
    JPEG 2000 files - *.jp2 (see the Note section)
    Portable Network Graphics - *.png (see the Note section)
    WebP - *.webp (see the Note section)
    Portable image format - *.pbm, *.pgm, *.ppm *.pxm, *.pnm (always supported)
    PFM files - *.pfm (see the Note section)
    Sun rasters - *.sr, *.ras (always supported)
    TIFF files - *.tiff, *.tif (see the Note section)
    OpenEXR Image files - *.exr (see the Note section)
    Radiance HDR - *.hdr, *.pic (always supported)
    Raster and Vector geospatial data supported by GDAL (see the Note section)
```

https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.4/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the  things I was missing.

Comment: You're welcome! Please mark as solved.