# Convert Jpg image to heice in python

Tags: python, django

Hey folks i need to Convert Jpg image to heic in python, any lead will be appreciateble

I try pillow but not supporting extension. It showing error of

```
unknown file extension: .heic
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54395735/how-to-work-with-heic-image-file-types-in-python